# Toy with Badly Cracked main PCB

Tags: pcb

Would someone knows what is the part showed on the attached picture ?
[image]
This comes from the inside of Indominus Rex toy GCT95 manufactured by Mattel. I'd like to replace it and have the beast back to life for my son.

Comment: If you mean that entire blue thing that's cracked across the upper right corner, that's a printed circuit board.  For a toy, it's almost certainly custom made **for that toy**, and isn't something that you can just buy.

Comment: And the big crack across top of board.

Comment: About a third of the board is broken.  It looks to be a two layer board so you could trace out the circuit and build it up on perf board, but if you have to ask here I fear the toy has become extinct.

Comment: draw a wiring diagram of the board ... translate it into a schematic diagram ... maybe you may be able to rebuild it on a perf board

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I suspect it's a single-layer board; I can't spot a via anywhere, and those 0-ohm resistors look like they're just being used as jumper links.

Comment: Looks like you can still buy these toys (sku: gct95) at some retailers. I could probably repair that PCB (if it were my child's toy), but I would just buy a whole new toy rather than go through the trouble.

Comment: Easier in the longrun to buy new, but Rocketmagnet's answer  combined with Chris Straton's comment would work.  On the other side, little Johnny will enjot the toy repaired or not.  Is the effort worth the investment?

Comment: If you have no mental tools to help guide you, this work will at least be "challenging." On the other hand, if your have a few basics, like being able to use a magnifier or binocular microscope to carefully trace out the details, this is just a matter of time. You can get there. How bad do you want this? That's the question. It is doable.

Comment: It would take maybe 15 minutes for someone with moderate skills to repair that board, including 5 minutes to let the epoxy set. The second time it happens will be more challenging.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the multiply fractured main circuit board shown in your picture is not repairable by less than extreme methods.  It's a cheap paper-phenolic board notorious for cracking when stressed, but can be cranked out in a factory for pennies.

You'd need to source a replacement, and such are not usually sold for mass market toys, especially not those of western banding and where the board is buried deep in side.  (One slight exception is that spare boards are available for some cheap drones; but there the board is exposed, and much more likely to suffer crash damage - and even then, only a minority of brands sell them).  Even in the unlikely event they were sold, questions about finding where to buy things are off topic on this site.

If this were an item of orders of magnitude higher value than it is, a skilled technician could probably attempt to glue the board back together then repair enough of the broken traces to get those sensor/actuator wires re-integrated into the circuit.  Or to re-assemble it enough to take a picture and then transfer the components to the new board designed from that.  But that's hundreds to thousands of dollars of labor equivalent unjustified for a simple toy, unless you have the skill to do it yourself and the emotional attachment to an irreplaceable treasure warrants it.

An interesting alternative would be to try to replace the board with something custom; if the child is reaching an age where programming projects become plausible, a "brain transplant" based on some experimenter MCU platform (Arduino, circuit python, Espruino, whatever) could be quite rewarding - but would take a lot of work to figure out the sensor/actuator interface.

Or maybe you can find another of the toy broken in a different way, and get the board from that.

Comment: FWIW I don't disagree with the close votes, but wanted to give the parent a bit more detail and alternatives than fit in a comment.  If the question ends up closed, it ends up closed.

Comment: The only other scenario where it would be worth it to fix that board would be if a highly skilled technician was playing with their child's or grandchild's toy and broke it -- *then* heaven and earth would be moved to fix the @#$% thing, preferably before Mom or Dad found out.

Comment: @TimWescott what's your ethical take on pre-gifting speakerectomy?

Comment: If it prevents a murder by a frazzled young parent, sure!  There were one or two toys in our household when my kids were little that had series resistors in the speaker wires, so that the things would make all those fun noises *quietly*.

Comment: Given that the board is almost certainly just one-sided and holds like 20 components in total, I don't think recreating it is a matter of hundreds or thousands of dollars. More like one evening to draw the schematic and replicate the layout (no thinking required, just do it exactly the way you see it), and another evening to solder everything on. Still certainly not cheaper than buying a new toy, but then there's a priceless "daddy fixed it for you" aspect included and the kid can watch and learn, too.

Comment: In a non-commercial environment, recreating/fixing the circuit for the fun of it, or for knowing that your kid can enjoy their toy again, or both, can be worth many hours of effort.

Comment: @TooTea "an evening" of time from someone capable of doing this is hundreds of dollars in equivalent professional labor.  It may well account differently, but that's what such an effort is worth as an effort.

Answer (score 7):

**Easy[er] option — repair the board**

Good news is that yes, PCBs can be repaired.

I can't see from the photo if it's one-sided or two-sided, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have internal layers.

The amount of work requires is directly proportional to the number of broken traces. If you're a beginner, consider some 15 minutes per trace, because you won't always get it right the first time.

In theory it should go like this: scrape off the insulation, use solder and flux to wet the conductor, prepare a piece of wire, strip the ends, wet the ends with solder, solder wire end to the exposed part of the trace.

Sometimes, it's easier to use a multimeter (or just eyes) to figure out where the trace is going, and solder a patch to exposed component lead rather than to the point where the trace was broken.

In any case, glue the board to something more solid or it will break again...

**More hardcore — reverse engineer**

Now, the part: I'm assuming you're talking about the 14-pin U1. it's not always easy to identify parts definitively.

Edit: **NY4B065B** from https://www.nyquest.com.tw/tw/product/SpeechIC/NY4_Series

> Single-Chip 4-bit MCU with 1-Ch Speech & 8 I/O

A good guess is to start with what the toy used to do. My guess, given that there are buttons (?) and "speaker" visible on the board that it's a very primitive microcontroller that has both behaviour and voice of the toy hardcoded. If that's the case, you'd have to read out the code from the microcontroller. That's generally doable, but requires knowing what to do what what specific microcontroller that was.

(There's also a chance it's a generic sound generator, perhaps someone can comment on that).

Comment: There's really no reason to try read out the MCU; either repair the board, move the MCU to a new board, build a replacement that does some other fun behavior... or more realistically, recognize that it's a $40 toy still on the market that broke.

Comment: I think I found the part too. hooray!

Comment: Cheers, @ChrisStratton I've clarified that the two approaches are in fact alternatives.

Comment: Alternative to real reverse engineering: Just replace the board with a suitable alternative (e.g. Arduino) and replicate the original behaviour. I can see “SPK”, “MOUTH”, “PAW” and “PWM” pins, it’s probably just some kind of dog. Could be a fun lesson for the child to add their own behaviour.

Comment: It looks like the board is just one-sided. There's not a single via or THT part to be seen, plus there's a bunch of 0-ohm SMD "resistor" jumpers to let traces pass underneath. The board doesn't seem to be complex enough to need two layers and these jumpers at the same time.

Comment: Having done *many* PCB repairs in a previous life I will say that this is almost certainly repairable with a little superglue, a scalpel and a soldering iron.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see from the picture, the detached part doesn't even contain any component. So just linking the missing connections to and within the board may be enough to repair it.

It's worth trying. But it's possible that it doesn't work for an unknown reason despite checking everything.

It takes soldering skill to repair traces. Take a magnifying glass.

If it's a one side PCB, glue some tape on the back to hold things together.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from the picture, but the PCB is actually broken in 3 pieces: there's the corner which is obviously detached, and there's the upper quarter which is also broken off.

Comment: Yes the upper quarter which is not completely detached is more problematic but not impossible to repair. I don't see sensitive components on it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much this is worth to you, you can certainly repair this kind of damage. Forget about what others are saying about trying to reverse engineer it and build a brand new one.

Just literally glue the pieces carefully back together, then repair the broken copper tracks.

There are several good videos on YouTube about repairing broken tracks on circuit boards.

[Repairing broken traces on a circuit board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ref9JHUf-uw)
[image: Repairing a damaged track]

All you'll need is:

- A soldering iron
- some solder
- some thin copper wire
- a razor blade
- patience and practice

Carefully scrape the blue layer away to expose the copper on either side of the crack. Then solder the thin copper wire across the crack.

Comment: This *was* raised as a possibility.  But the multitude of fractures mean it will likely need some physical reinforcement.  Given the simplicity of the circuit, doing a complete clone based on photographs as previously suggested may prove simpler, and definitely more robust if done on fiberglass substrate - albeit at a longer waiting time.  At the very least, if you are going to attempt to repair traces, *take pictures first* so that if damage worsense making a new board remains a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

A long shot is that dead or damaged versions of the toy are available on ebay "for parts".  OK, a *very* long shot ...

Answer (score 1):

The Label "Vpp" strongly suggests to me that the chip on the board is a microcontroller of some sort. The PCB and the programming of the microcontroller are almost certainly custom to that particular toy. The part number printed on the microcontroller may be a custom one representing custom preprogramming, I certainly wasn't able to get anywhere with a quick search. It's highly unlikely you will be able to buy a replacement.

Given the relative simplicity of the PCB (it looks like it's at-most two layer and possiblly only single layer), it would certainly be possible to trace it out (you may have to remove some of the components and/or use a multimeter for some of the tracing), build a clone in a peice of PCB design software and get it made by someone like oshpark, then transplant the chip from the old board to the new board but the time and cost involved would almost certainly be more than the toy is worth.

Answer (score -3):

How did it become broken? If *you* broke it then *you* organise repairing it, even if that means finding a local maker/hackerspace or paying a specialist. If the child broke it then it's his problem: if he smashes his toys then his toys don't work any more.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks a million everyone 

Comment: Got plenty of food for thoughts 

Comment: Good luck. As everybody has said you've got a tricky one, and don't be worried about looking for help with the physical repair.